# SQL Count subquery in date range is reporting all results instead of results by individual

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get a subquery that will count the number of cases charged to an individual during a specific time period. The current version instead reports every charge counted during the time period and not just for the individual. How do I modify the following query to output a count of the unique tblCsCases.CauseNumber associated with each BookedLastName? I need the BookedLastNames chosen to be limited by the general WHERE by ChargeDescription, Statute, and ChargeLanguage but that same limitation should not be applied to the CrimeCount which should only be limited by date.

```
SELECT
     substring (tblCsCases.FileNumber,4,6) AS [FileNumber]
    ,tblCsCharge.ChargeCode
    ,tblCsCases.BookedLastName
    ,tblCsCases.BookedFirstName
    ,(SELECT COUNT(tblCsCases.CauseNumber)
        FROM tblCsCases
        WHERE tblCsCases.IssuedDate >= @EndDate
        AND tblCsCases.IssuedDate <= GETDATE()) AS CrimeCount
FROM
tblCsCases
INNER JOIN tblCsCharge 
    ON tblCsCases.FileNumber = tblCsCharge.FileNumber
WHERE tblCsCases.IssuedDate >= @StartDate
AND
tblCsCases.IssuedDate <= @EndDate
AND
tblCsCharge.Statute IN (N'571.030')
AND
tblCsCharge.ChargeDescription LIKE '%sub%'
AND
tblCsCharge.ChargeLanguage LIKE '%exhibit%'

ORDER By
tblCsCases.BookedLastName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link your COUNT to the BookedLastName / BookedFirstName (or some other unique identifier that identifies a person). To do this, you will need to use a table alias or two. So, try this for your query:

```
SELECT
     substring (Cases.FileNumber,4,6) AS [FileNumber]
    ,Charge.ChargeCode
    ,Cases.BookedLastName
    ,Cases.BookedFirstName
    ,(SELECT COUNT(c2.CauseNumber)
        FROM tblCsCases c2
        WHERE c2.IssuedDate >= @EndDate
            AND c2.IssuedDate <= GETDATE()
            AND c2.BookedLastName = Cases.BookedLastName
            AND c2.BookedFirstName = Cases.BookedFirstName
        ) AS CrimeCount
FROM tblCsCases as Cases
INNER JOIN tblCsCharge as Charge
    ON Cases.FileNumber = Charge.FileNumber
WHERE 
    Cases.IssuedDate >= @StartDate
    AND Cases.IssuedDate <= @EndDate
    AND Charge.Statute IN (N'571.030')
    AND Charge.ChargeDescription LIKE '%sub%'
    AND Charge.ChargeLanguage LIKE '%exhibit%'
ORDER By
    Cases.BookedLastName
```

Comment: This works! I had to change which columns were being picked to make it function (apparently IssuedDate is null way too frequently) but...oh my god it works! I've been trying to figure this out on my own for weeks!!

Comment: As an aside, why does utilizing an alias for the tblCsCases in the original query and another alias in the sub query make this work?

Comment: If you don't use an alias, the query analyzer can't tell which 'table' you are referencing - the outer, or the inner.  Also, I think the code looks cleaner with a good alias.

Comment: Thank you, Vergil. This is something that will help a lot in the future as well!

Comment: Glad to help, @JackOfTales.